# Limit filter inside scope of include filter not working in loopback

Tags: limit, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I have two tables, **'categoryinfo'** and **'accounttag'**.

The two tales have the following relation:

categoryinfo **hasMany** accounttag

accounttag **belongsTo** categoryinfo

I want to apply limit on:

1. the number of categories (set to 5) and
2. number of accounttags fetched from the relation for each category (set to 10)

However, the limit filter inside the scope of the include filter is not working properly and is fetching less results than the **set limit** for each category but the database **contains more valid entries** than the **limit value.**

`categoryinfo.find(
    {
        where: {
            valid: 1
        },
        include: [
            {
                relation: 'accounttag',
                scope: {
                    where: {
                        valid: 1
                    },
                    order: 'rank ASC',
                    limit: 10,
                }
            }
        ],
        order: 'modifiedon DESC',
        limit: 5
    }
)`

Is there any way to achieve the required result using the same filters?

Comment: i'm not sure about it, but can you please remove the [] from your include filter ? it's useless when you have 1 relation

Answer (score 0):

With the **current stable Version of Loopback** you cannot filter on Level 2 properties for Relational Databases. These are some of the Issues raised on the same in Loopback

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/517
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/683

> As a matter of fact you might want to look into [native sql queries in loopback](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Executing-native-SQL.html) and
>   do the filtering there, or might need to use native javascript array
>   methods for filtering

Comment: what do you mean by filter, all filters or just limit filter? because I can filter on level 2 LB3 (MongoDs) it depends on the connector

Comment: what is the database connector you are using ?

Comment: I am using mongodb

Comment: It is only possible in mongo db as of now as it as nosql db and andy rdbms it is not possible please look at those issues thanks for pointing out i missed it in my answer, upodated my ans to